# React responsive layout without CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, responsive

I'm wondering what is the best approach to implement layouting in React app.

#### Basics

Let's say we want to have 4 components laid out in simple grid. The most basic way would be something like this.

```
<svg width={width} height={height} viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}>
  <A color="red" x={0} y={0} width={width/2} height={height/2} />
  <B color="blue" x={width/2} y={0} width={width/2} height={height/2} />
  <B color="green" x={0} y={height/2} width={width/2} height={height/2} />
  <A color="yellow" x={width/2} y={height/2} width={width/2} height={height/2} />
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWOXvV?editors=0010

It will work fine, but typing explicit size values is error-prone and not dev-friendly. What if we could use percentage values (0 - 1) instead?

#### Simple container

```
const Container = ({x, y, width, height, children}) => {
  return (
    <g transform={`translate(${x}, ${y})`}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, { // this creates a copy
        x: child.props.x * width,
        y: child.props.y * height,
        width: child.props.width * width,
        height: child.props.height * height
      }))}
    </g>
  );
};

 <svg width={width} height={height} viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}>
  <Container width={width} height={height}>{/* one root container is given real pixel size */}
    <Container width={1/2}>{/* it's children recursively use 0-1 coordinates */}
      <A color="red" height={1/2} />
      <B color="green" y={1/2} height={1/2} />
    </Container>
    <Container x={1/2} width={1/2}>
      <B color="blue" height={1/2} />
      <A color="yellow" y={1/2} height={1/2} />
    </Container>
  </Container>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWEmVd?editors=0010

In this case we'll allow Container component to map it's children relative values to real pixel values. It's much easier to use.

#### Layout container

Another step would be to create layout container, f.e. HContainer that simply lays its children horizontally.

```
const HContainer = ({ x, y, width, height, children }) => {
  const c = React.Children.toArray(children);
  const ratio = width / c.reduce((sum, child) => (sum + child.props.width), 0);
  return (
    <g transform={`translate(${x}, ${y})`}>
      {c.reduce((result, child) => {
        const width = child.props.width * ratio;
        result.children.push(React.cloneElement(child, { // this creates a copy
          x: result.x,
          y: 0,
          width,
          height
        }));
        result.x += width;
        return result;
      }, { x: 0, children: [] }).children}
    </g>
  );
};

<svg width={width} height={height} viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}>
  <HContainer width={width} height={height}>{/* one root container is given real pixel size */}
    <Container width={1/4}>{/* it's children recursively use 0-1 coordinates */}
      <A color="red" height={1/2} />
      <B color="green" y={1/2} height={1/2} />
    </Container>
    <VContainer width={3/4}>
      <B color="blue" />
      <A color="yellow" />
      <HContainer height={1/2}>
        <B color="pink" />
        <A color="violet" width={3} />
        <B color="#333" />
      </HContainer>
    </VContainer>
  </HContainer>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRpwBe?editors=0010

#### Responsive components

Let's say we'd like some components be removed when width or height is below some value. You'd probably use conditional rendering like this.

```
const MinWidth = ({ children, width, minWidth, ... others }) => {
  return minWidth > width ? null : <Container width={width} {... others }>{ children }</Container>;
};

<svg width={width} height={height} viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}>
  <HContainer width={width} height={height}>{/* one root container is given real pixel size */}
    <Container width={1/4}>{/* it's children recursively use 0-1 coordinates */}
      <A color="red" height={1/2} />
      <B color="green" y={1/2} height={1/2} />
    </Container>
    <VContainer width={3/4}>
      <B color="blue" />
      <MinHeight height={1} minHeight={80}>
        <A color="yellow" />
      </MinHeight>
      <HContainer height={1/2}>
        <B color="pink" />
        <A color="violet" width={3} />
        <MinWidth width={1} minWidth={60}>
          <B color="#333" />
        </MinWidth>
      </HContainer>
    </VContainer>
  </HContainer>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNJZGd?editors=0010

But this leaves empty spaces where skipped components used to be. Layout containers should be able to expand rendered components to fill available space.

#### Responsive layout

And here's the tricky part. I can see no other way to see if component will render, but to instantiate and render it (and it's children). Then, if I lay 3 child components within avaialable space and discover that 4th should not be rendered I'll have to re-render previous 3. It feels like breaking React flow.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Because I'm trying to understand how React component should properly manage its children. Also there are render targets that don't support CSS.

Comment: You are trying to implement 2008 year of web development. We named it "table layout".))))

Comment: @m1gu3l Writing your css inline with components will help you help manage your css along react's parent-child relationships.  A child's <div> shouldn't affect parent's <div> too much if you're keeping to best practices.

Now, if you have a specific need for css-less react for some reason, maybe due to some technological demand, then we can certainly work with you on this.  Otherwise, "react without css" is just an unnecessary anti-pattern.

Comment: @DenTemple , it's more trying to wrap my head around how such thing should be done within React itself. I know how to do it with CSS, it's rather trivial with flexbox, but then - flexbox doesn't work on svg, and f.e. canvas doesn't support css at all.

Comment: finally, a js developer implementing layouts in its imperative language, oh wait, you used svg instead doing the maths... :P Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use flexbox in inline styles. You are already using inline style from the look of your code. [Here is some help](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Flexbox is CSS module and it won't work on React components - only on their HTML DOM representation. That's why I used SVG in examples, SVG doesn't support Flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-flexbox-grid](https://github.com/roylee0704/react-flexbox-grid) to layout components easily without touching any CSS.

```
const {Grid, Row, Col} = require('react-flexbox-grid');

const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={6} md={3}>Hello, world!</Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: This actually uses CSS Flexbox underneath.